# converting file: url to path

Tags: strings, xstring

I am creating LaTeX files using a template engine. The problem I am running into is that the template engine is designed for generating web pages and generates URLs for external files, such as images. And my LaTeX files also use images.

So, I am getting strings like `file:///C:/temp/image.jpeg` or `file:///tmp/image.jpg`, but for `\includegraphics` to accept the file, I need to strip of the `file://` (or even `file:///` for Windows paths) from the URL I get.

How can I realize this in LaTeX? Preferably in a way that works for both Windows and Unix paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this code

```
\usepackage{xstring}

% command to extract the filename out of a file: URL.
% Input that isn't a file: URL is left alone    
\newcommand\GetFileName[2]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{file://}{%
  \StrMid{#1}{10}{10}[\colon]%
  \IfStrEq{\colon}{:}{%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{8}[#2]}{%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{7}[#2]}}{%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{0}[#2]}%
}

% usage    
\GetFileName{file:///C:/Users/Bart/AppData/Local/Temp/logo.jpg}{\imagefile}
\includegraphics[height=1in]{\imagefile}
```